# I can't print blank lines when reading values from a text file using awk in a bash script

Tags: awk

`awk` is behaving very strangely in my script. I am trying to read values from a text file (see `file.txt` below).

`awk` is ignoring blank spaces in my script, but when I test the `awk` statement on its own (in a test script for bugging) it provides the correct output.

Here is `file.txt`:

```
cain
jon
chris

johny
anthony

jose
```

Here is my `awk` statement: `awk '{print $1}' file.txt`

This is the output when the `awk` statement is in my script:

```
cain
jon
chris   
johny
anthony    
jose
```

This is the output when the `awk` statement is isolated in my test script:

```
cain
jon
chris

johny
anthony

jose
```

I tried using `\n` as a delimiter but I get the same result.

Why is `awk` behaving differently in my script and when it is isolated?

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: Can you include the output of `sed -n '=;l' file.txt`

Comment: (note that `awk` should _not_ ignore blank lines, use `awk 'NF{print $1}'` to ignore blank lines)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I know that `sed` would work in this case but I am being told to use `awk` for this script that I am working on

Comment: [cross-posting](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24560664/753731) is usually frowned upon here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it can be a bug in your script, not `awk` itself.

The situation which `awk` behave like this is when double newline is set to `RS` variable:

```
awk '{print $1}' RS='\n|\n\n' file
```

You should check if your script had changed the value of `RS`.